# Display Cards in UI in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to Display Cards in Canvas programmatically from Script onClick. I have Successfully shuffled my cards and stored in player1 and player2 Array (26 random card to each player). I have create a basic players zone for player1 and player2. My approach is when i click the button the cards get distributed in their respective zones with images, stored in cards

I am new to unity and have no idea to render images to Canvas, I tried creating gameObject Canvas with help of google and stackoverflow question but i didn't solve my problem. I have store my full project on dropbox LINK: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ofx9m6kaljpiecz/AAC7q7ufgAK1jlPHOfsGJWkPa?dl=0.
Canvas Image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y118yboj9hx0i52/Screenshot%20%2833%29.png?dl=0

Here my main HelloWord.cs file

```
public class HelloWorld : MonoBehaviour
{
    Sprite sprite;
    List<string> player1 = new List<string>();
    List<string> player2 = new List<string>();
    public static string[] suits = new string[] { "spades", "hearts", "clubs", "diamonds" };
    public static string[] values = new string[] { "ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "jack", "queen", "king" };
    public List<string> deck;
    Texture2D myTexture;

    public void PlayCards()
    {
        deck = GenerateDeck();
        Shuffle(deck);
    }

    public void distributeCard()
    {
        for (var x = 1; x <= 26; x++)
        {
            player1.Add(deck[x]);
            foreach (var item in player1)
            {
                print("Player 1 Cards:" + item.ToString());
            }
        }
        for (var y = 26; y <= 52; y++)
        {
            player2.Add(deck[y]);
            foreach (var item in player2)
            {
                print("Player 2 Cards:" + item.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    public void onClick()
    {
        PlayCards();
        distributeCard();
    }

    public static List<string> GenerateDeck()
    {
        List<string> newDeck = new List<string>();
        foreach(string s in suits)
        {
            foreach(string v in values)
            {
                newDeck.Add(v  +"_of_"  + s);

            }
        }
        return newDeck;
    }
    void Shuffle<T>(List<T> list)
    {
        System.Random random = new System.Random();
        int n = list.Count;
        while (n > 1)
        {

           int k = random.Next(n);
            n--;
            T temp = list[k];
            list[k] = list[n];
            list[n] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a UI Element called "RawImage". That is just a single Texture to be shown in your UI layer on your canvas. It can be added from the editor in  UI -> Raw Image .

You can assign a material or a texture.

The element UnityEngine.UI.RawImage has a property 'material' that you can assign anytime. You can use that to assign materials you have prepared, one for each card.

When using a material, be sure to set the shader "Unlit/Color" or "Unlit/Transparent", because normal shaders using light will show a black image on the UI layer.